# How to name columns with ascending value

Tags: r

I have a general question about how to name columns of a matrix using `colnames()`

I know I can use

```
colnames(data) <- c("Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 4", "Site 5")
```

To name 5 columns with these headings. But in my case I have 8000 columns that I want to name "Site.(number)". Is there a way to do this without having to type out 8000 names? There must be, I am just very new to coding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` function and name your columns as follows:

```r
col <- seq(2)
col_names <- paste0("Site", " ", col)
data <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=c(2,2))
data

#   a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 2
names(data) <- col_names
data
#     Site 1 Site 2
# 1      1      2
# 2      2      2
```

Change the number inside the `seq` which is (2) in this case to the number you want (8000) in your case.

## Edit

As per Gregor's suggestion, if the separator you want is a space, you can use `paste` instead of `paste0` as follows.

```
col <- seq(2)
col_names <- paste("Site", col)
#for a different separator other than space, you can specify sep
col_names <- paste("Site", col, sep = "_")
```

Comment: `paste0` is a convenience function for *not* using spaces because `paste` by default uses a space separator. `paste0("Site", " ", col)` can be rewritten as `paste("Site", col)`. (Other than that, great answer!)

Comment: @Gregor, you're right but I'm in the habit of using `paste0` than `paste` for not writing out `sep` if a different one is required.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in order from 1 to 8000, you can use this

```
colnames(df) <- paste('Scale', 1:8000)
```

### **Additionally**

A helpful function for you in the future may be `rename` if you work with tidyr. You can use `rename_all` to rename all columns like the following example

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(`1` = 1:4, `2` = 5:8, `3` = 9:12)
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    `1`   `2`   `3`
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     9
2     2     6    10
3     3     7    11
4     4     8    12
```

```
df %>% 
  rename_all(.funs = ~paste('Scale', .))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  `Scale 1` `Scale 2` `Scale 3`
      <int>     <int>     <int>
1         1         5         9
2         2         6        10
3         3         7        11
4         4         8        12
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll incorporate it and keep it in mind for the future

Comment: Looks better! `rename` is a great addition. I'd recommend deleting the `purrr` bit, or at least moving it to the bottom. No need to lead with the weakest recommendation. And generally, on Stack Overflow, unless it's been a *long* time and you really want to call attention to it, no need to call out edits. Anyone can view the edit history of the answer by clicking the "Edited X mins ago" link at the bottom.